# Create iso, which is installable using the command 'dd'

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, debian, iso

I created a program which creates an ISO image using genisoimage

`sudo genisoimage -rational-rock -cache-inodes -joliet -full-iso9660-filenames -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -output "../${ISONAME}" .`

and isohybird afterwards

`sudo isohybrid ${ISONAME}`

It works fine when I install the outputted *.iso file using the program UNetbootin on an USB stick, but when I try to use it usign `dd`-command, it does not boot. Did I forget  a flag / parameter or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "bless" the generated ISO image with [isohybrid](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid).

Comment: Forgot to mention this. I did "bless" the image after genisoimage with isohybrid `sudo isohybrid ${ISONAME}`